# Qneat3 / shortest distance calc sensitive to altitude?

Tags: qgis, network, shortest-path, altitude

I'm trying to calculate shortest distance using Qneat3 (using both the shortest path and OD-matrices for different purposes). And am wondering if there is any possobility to factor in altitide (it is a very montanous region) to acurately represent the distances travelled? or does the plugin already do this? seem not to find information on this anywhere in the ether..

Frida

Comment: Even in mountinous regions, elevation change is unlikely to make a noticable difference

Comment: hmm, i guess, since the roads cant be too steep (without needing to circle a mountain eg.) thanks!